# woocommerce add_to_cart

Tags: woocommerce

When I program:

```
$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $group_product_id, 1);
```

with `$group_product_id` being the product post ID (e.g. 300), the shopping cart shows a quantity of 2 not 1.

When I directly enter the URL (e.g.http://www.mystore.com/shop/stuff?add_to_cart=300), the shopping cart shows a quantity of 1 (the correct expected behavior).

Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Thank you.

P.S. Bonus question: is there any way to program adding multiple items to the cart (not grouped or variations) before taking the user to the cart page?

Answer (score 1):

Grouped products cannot be added to cart directly. Group product is actually a group of simple products. So `$group_product_id` should be the id of any of the simple products which constitute the grouped product.

Answer (score 0):

The first two parameters you must use on $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart, are, $product->id and/or quantity to add. The post id has nothing to do here.

You can yes add multiple products at once using ajax calls, but is not so simple to describe on a comment, will depend on your configuration, your theme, etc, but yes, it´s posible, in fact i recently did something like that. The point is to use syncronized ajax calls that actualy call the add_to_cart function. You can use jquery for triggering many add to cart buttons at same time.